# spring boot bean to handle xml string to swagger model casting

Tags: java, ios, xml, spring, spring-mvc

Anyone have an example of setting up spring boot server so that an xml response of a swagger client can be cast to its corresponding model.

```
io.swagger.client.ApiException: Content type "application/xml; charset=UTF-8" is not supported for type: class io.swagger.client.model.Pet
```

at io.swagger.client.ApiClient.deserialize(ApiClient.java:848)

I tried to always deserialize with a cast and commented out the apiexception.

```
    } else {
        return (T) respBody;
//            throw new ApiException(
//                    "Content type \"" + contentType + "\" is not supported for type: " + returnType,
//                    response.code(),
//                    response.headers().toMultimap(),
//                    respBody);
    }
```

But then I'm getting a ClassCastException error.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to io.swagger.client.model.Pet
```

when I try to use the Pet store example from editor.swagger.io as a java client.

Then I tried adding to SpringEntry.java in my spring boot server.

```
@Bean
Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller() {
    Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
    marshaller.setClassesToBeBound(Pet.class);
    return marshaller;
}
```

But it does not seem to hit that.

I have been looking at https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/oxm.html for how spring boot converts xml to java object.

Comment: My workaround was to set the return type in the client api from Pet to String.  Then autowire and call the marshaller.
  'final StringReader is=new StringReader(xmlString);
          final Source source=new StreamSource(is); Pet pet = (Pet) marshaller.unmarshal(source); '

Comment: try catch SAXParseException